# How to prevent running two instances of Install Shield wizard in the same time?

Tags: installation, installshield

How to prevent running two instances of Install Shield wizard in the same time

I would like to allow User to run only one instance of Install Shield wizard in the same time

Answer (score 1):

What project type are you using?  If you are using MSI there's already a mutex that prevents more then one execute sequence pre machine and one ui sequence per process.

If you are using a pure InstallScript project, you need to implement a mutex:

[How to access my application's Mutex through InstallScript?](http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?t=153027)